# How to check if value is in list

Tags: c++, stl

I have list l like  `list<pair<int,int>>` . How to check if x
`pair<int,int> x=make_pair(5,6)` is in list l ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
std::find(l.begin(), l.end(), x) != l.end()
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
auto it = std::find(lst.begin(), lst.end(), x);
if ( it != lst.end() )
{
   //x found
}
```

Comment: why do you need condition? Why not just std::find() ?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes. You don't need it, as `==` is defined for `std::pair<int,int>`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the algorithm [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
std::list<std::pair<int, int>> my_list;
my_list.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 2));
my_list.push_back(std::make_pair(3, 2));

auto i = std::find(my_list.begin(), my_list.end(), std::make_pair(3, 2));
if (i != my_list.end())
{
    // Found it.
}
```